# HTML Form save to server-side text file

Tags: javascript, php, html

All.

I've found many-a scripts which save form input to the local computer, I.E. downloading a text document with the submitted information, however I am trying to develop a html form which, when the 'submit' button is pressed, saves the text in the text field(s) as a single text document. The closest I've come is the following (Sorry, can't find where I got this code from originally. Hope that's okay :/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
if(isset($_POST['fileWrite']) && !empty($_POST['fileWrite'])) {
$fileWrite = $_POST['fileWrite'];
}
if($fileWrite) {
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file"); //Make sure you have permission
fwrite($fh, $fileWrite);
fclose($fh);
exec('/your/command /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="some" name="someName" method="post" action="/../PastEntries/file.txt">
<input type="text" id="some1" class="someClass" value="" name="fileWrite"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submitClass"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I get the error "Cannot POST /../www/file.txt"
I'm new to PHP, and have no idea how to fix this. I hope someone more experienced can help or provide an alternative!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: lots of problems there. The php code is within a `script` tag, the action of the form needs to be ( in this case ) a php file and what does the `exec` function do?

Comment: @RamRaider I've got no idea. Probably should have done some research on the topic before asking. I only need a little script to save a textbox to a server-side *.txt file, but I've never done anything with php. I got this code from some other forum, who claimed that it worked. I couldn't get it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had was fiddling around with your code to see if i can make it work. Below is the fixed version.

```
<html>
<head>

<?php

$fileWrite = '';    
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
if(isset($_POST['fileWrite']) && !empty($_POST['fileWrite'])) {
$fileWrite = $_POST['fileWrite'].PHP_EOL;
}
if($fileWrite) {
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file"); //Make sure you have permission
fwrite($fh, $fileWrite);
fclose($fh);
}
?>

</head>

<body>
<form id="some" name="someName" method="post">
<input type="text" id="some1" class="someClass" value="" name="fileWrite"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submitClass"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have worked around what @RamRider had pointed out earlier and added **.PHP_EOL** that enables new line break ([check manual for better understanding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)). Use this code and let us know if there is any errors. I will try to help as much as i can.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry I was a while, but again, its not going. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong somewhere else, but I copied that code, uploaded it to my webserver, visited it, typed something in and hit submit, only for the page to reload with no result.

Comment: Just want to know: are you running it thru localhost? do you have the file saved as PHP?

Comment: I was running it through Brackets live preview: [link](http://brackets.io/), which ended up being the problem. After actually uploading it to a free domain with ftp, it worked fine. My bad. Thank you very much @Syfer

Comment: I had a feeling. PHP files need a server to run on. It can be run on localhost using wamp or xamp. Good to hear it worked for you. It would be get an up for this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you could do something like this. The form action is removed entirely so the form POSTS to the same page - the request is interpreted by PHP and the data written to a text file.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $filename=__DIR__ . '\\file.txt';
        file_put_contents( $filename, implode( PHP_EOL,$_POST ) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Save Form data to text file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="some" name="someName" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="some1" class="someClass" value="" name="fileWrite"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submitClass"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got a very similar result with this code as well: [link](https://s22.postimg.org/dt711wey9/Screen_Shot_2017-05-01_at_9.32.57_am.png). As oppose to my previous code: [link](https://s3.postimg.org/4zbncjdb7/Screen_Shot_2017-05-01_at_9.36.22_am.png). Considering that I have zero experience in the field of php, I doubt I'm going to get anywhere with either of these results. :/

Comment: The above code worked fine for me. Didn't have to change anything.